# loop throught column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i want to loop throught column in a file excel instead of just column A but i didn't succeed on that . Can you help me ?
it s the 7 line (Filepath) that i m blocked in . if i changed column A for icol it doesn't work .

```
Set workboo = Workbooks.OpeN("C:\Users\Desktop\list_files.xlsx")

Set worksh = workboo.Worksheets("List_File")

For j = 1 To 10
   icol = 2 * j - 1
   numRows = worksh.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row        
    For i = 2 To numRows
            Filepath = worksh.Range("A" & i).Value  'i changed column A for icol but it doesn t work 
            fso.CopyFile Filepath, Destination, True
        Next
```

Comment: Change ~Application.Rows to worksh.Rows~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through columns, it'll be easier to use `Cells` :

```
Filepath = worksh.Cells(i, icol).Value
```

---

And this :

```
numRows = worksh.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
```

should be

```
numRows = worksh.Cells(worksh.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: in fact , you are right . But i changed and there is always a problem in that line " automation error "

Comment: I commented that ~Application.Rows~ be changed to ~worksh.Rows~ and you also endorsed it. But testing for this line I am getting correct numRows even with ~Application.Rows~ and this line is not throwing any error. Seek your guidance on this issue.

Comment: @JeanLo : You get an automation error on `numRows = ...`? Straaaaange... I don't have an explaination for this, I don't even understand how there can be an error here... Is that part of a much larger program?